# How to make Leaflet marker interactive only for click events?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, interactive

I'd like to have a marker (with DivIcon icon) which does not capture any mouse events besides clicks. Is this feasible and how to achieve it?

Here is a fiddle showing the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/A1an/dcut125e/ -- The icon on the map should stay visible when the mouse pointer crosses the text in the polygon, but should also react to (and capture) click events.

Tried also with bubblingMouseEvents with no success:

```
iconLabel=L.divIcon({html:"This text blocks events"});
labeledMarker=L.marker([39.83711,-3.464459], {icon:iconLabel, bubblingMouseEvents:true});
labeledMarker.addTo(map);
```

Any directions would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Besides from missing a semi-colon at the end of one of your lines, you forgot to add any click event handlers to the `L.DivIcon` which you added to the polygon.

You must also use the syntax `new L.DivIcon` as this ensures you are instantiating a new `L.DivIcon`.

I've updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dcut125e/3/) which now keeps the map marker icon showing when hovering over the `L.DivIcon`, and attached two click events which detect if you're clicking on the polygon itself for the DivIcon added to it.

Comment: You added the same mouseover function to the label which is not making it "transparent" to other mouse events. In my case I do not have the possibility to attach a similar function handler to the marker label

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it is not possible to make a marker interactive only for certain events since it uses the pointer-events css attribute to make it interactive or not, which in turn does not specify which events are emitted, it is just all or nothing.

What can be done is instead to explicitly fire events on the underlying element, hence making the label act as if it was not there for such events. The trick leverages the technique of hiding the label, then getting the next element at the mouse coordinates, then restoring the label and finally firing a new event on the underlying element. Unfortunately this does not seem to work in a jsfiddle but works like a charm in the real app

```
labeledMarker.on('mouseover',function(e) {
           old_disp=e.target._icon.style.display;
           e.target._icon.style.display='none';
           offset={top: e.originalEvent.clientY, left:e.originalEvent.clientX};
           underlying = document.elementFromPoint(offset.left,offset.top);
           e.target._icon.style.display=old_disp;
           var ev = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
           ev.initEvent("mouseover",true,true);
           ev.target = underlying;
           underlying.dispatchEvent(ev);
        });
```